# Sql Inner join or self join

Tags: sql-server, join

I have an sql table populated from a program and the data would look like this:

Primary key - Request ID
columns

```
Request ID  Session ID UserID LoginOperation     Time

1               1      Arun       Logon          8:00
2               1      Arun       Logoff         8:30
3               2      Sandy      Logon          7:55
4               2      Sandy      Logon Expired  8:38
```

Now what I need is

```
Request ID  Session ID UserID  LoginOperation    Time      Login Operation  Time

1              1       Arun    Logon             8:00      Logoff           8:30
3              2       Sandy   Logon             7:55      LogonExpired     8:38
```

SO I will need my logon information along with the log of time in a same row.

How can I achieve this?

Should I filter my 1st table with logon and then do the same for the second table by either logoff or logonexpired and then inner join both tables on session id. ?

Or can I do a self join on these tables with some where condition..

Please let me know your suggestions?

Hi ,

I have come up with the below query to get my log on information along with the log off time.

```
Select T.COGIPF_LOCALTIMESTAMP, T.COGIPF_SESSIONID, T.COGIPF_REQUESTID,
       T.COGIPF_STATUS, T.COGIPF_LOGON_OPERATION, T.COGIPF_USERNAME,
       T.COGIPF_USERID, T.COGIPF_NAMESPACE, T.COGIPF_CAMID,
       Z.COGIPF_LOCALTIMESTAMP as LogOffTime 
from [CognosAuditSampleDev].COGIPF_USERLOGON T 
    LEFT JOIN [CognosAuditSampleDev].COGIPF_USERLOGON Z on
        T.COGIPF_SESSIONID = Z.COGIPF_SESSIONID and
        Z.COGIPF_LOGON_OPERATION <>'Logon' 
where T.COGIPFSTATUS='Success' And Z.COGIPFSTATUS ='Success' And
      T.COGIPF_LOGON_OPERATION='Logon'
```

I found an issue when there is no logg off received for a logon , in this case the logon record is missing in my table even after I do a left join. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks,
Manikandan

Comment: What version of SQL? It can make a difference for this kind of query.

Comment: ...then again, as per @Joel Coehoorn, maybe not.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT r1.RequestID, r1.SessionID, r1.UserId, r1.LoginOperation, r1.Time
    , r2.LoginOperation, r2.Time 
FROM Requests r1
INNER JOIN Requests r2 on r2.SessionID = r1.SessionID and r2.LoginOperation <> 'Logon'
WHERE r1.LoginOperation = 'Logon'
```

You already mentioned a self-join in the question... you should just try it :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why put the 'Logon' in the WHERE clause, and the 'LogOff' in the join condition? Is there a reason to not put both of them together? (in either location)

Comment: @Flater It's just how I reason about joins. For inner join the two options are functionally equivalent, but when writing join conditions I tend to think about how to match records from the second table to the first. Then if I need to filter the first table, that's a process I look at when writing the where clause.

Comment: So the Request table here we are using will have records automatically inserted. so now since we are using a selfjoin and  modifying the table as per our need , I want to create a new table from our select statement and then pull in this table for my reporting purpose. So how will I create a new table with above select and If i  create a new table will it still automatically be updated as my Request table updates. Any suggestions is appreciated. Thanks for your help !!

Comment: Don't create a table, create a view. And even that is probably too much... just put that sql into your report. Also, you may want to use a left join instead of an INNER JOIN, so you can see rows for people who have logged in but not logged out yet.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn , what you told was right , I have to use a left join to see people who have logged in but not logged out or suppose if i dint get a record for logoff. I am using this code and having issues that if there is only one logon and there is no log off for that, the record is not being shown in my table. im breaking my heads and couldnot find out why I am not getting it. I am pasting the code below.

Comment: Select   T.COGIPF_LOCALTIMESTAMP , T.COGIPF_SESSIONID , T.COGIPF_REQUESTID , T.COGIPF_STATUS ,  T.COGIPF_LOGON_OPERATION , T.COGIPF_USERNAME , T.COGIPF_USERID , T.COGIPF_NAMESPACE , T.COGIPF_CAMID , Z.COGIPF_LOCALTIMESTAMP as LogOffTime from  [CognosAuditSampleDev].COGIPF_USERLOGON T
LEFT JOIN [CognosAuditSampleDev].COGIPF_USERLOGON Z
on  T.COGIPF_SESSIONID= Z.COGIPF_SESSIONID and Z.COGIPF_LOGON_OPERATION <>'Logon'
where T.COGIPF_STATUS='Success' And Z.COGIPF_STATUS ='Success' And T.COGIPF_LOGON_OPERATION='Logon'

Comment: SampleData Session ID  Request ID Name  TimeStamp Logon Operation
A9D1C6ECE29E37D177D80B0F9C43F3187F4573D547185B60867CF3611A1A1AEC ABC Manny 5:00:24 Logon
1234 BCS Ajay 5:00:45 Logon
1234 BDS Ajay 6:00:45 LogOff

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Can you think of what might be going on ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with a self `INNER JOIN` and comparing the sessionIDs and requestIDs. For example:

```
SELECT t1.RequestID, t1.SessionID, t1.UserID, t1.LoginOperation, t1.Time, 
       t2.LoginOperation, t2.Time
FROM Test t1
    INNER JOIN Test t2 on t2.SessionID = t1.SessionID
WHERE t1.RequestID < t2.RequestID
```

This has been tested on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a3682/2).

Enjoy!

Comment: Hey. I understand using t1.Request iD < t2. Request ID eliminates my need to filter on log on and log off on each self tables. But it should be like t1.requestid <> t2.request id.. Is t1.requestid< t2.requestid mean the same. I am getting duplicate records when I use <> instead of < .Please explain what does < do ..

Comment: @RamasamyManikandan the `t1.requestID < t2.requestID` is just an arithmetic operation that checks if the requestID of table 2 is greater than the requestID for table 1. That way the 2nd table will always have a login operation that happened after the 1st table's entry. Using `t1.requestID <> t2.requestID` (which means if the 2 ids does not equal to each other) will return this result plus the same result in reverse, hence your "duplicate records".

Comment: Thanks for the Information. I am  using the below code and facing some issue.Select T.COGIPF_LOCALTIMESTAMP , T.COGIPF_SESSIONID , T.COGIPF_REQUESTID , T.COGIPF_STATUS , T.COGIPF_LOGON_OPERATION , T.COGIPF_USERNAME , T.COGIPF_USERID , T.COGIPF_NAMESPACE , T.COGIPF_CAMID , Z.COGIPF_LOCALTIMESTAMP as LogOffTime from [CognosAuditSampleDev].COGIPF_USERLOGON T LEFT JOIN [CognosAuditSampleDev].COGIPF_USERLOGON Z on T.COGIPF_SESSIONID= Z.COGIPF_SESSIONID and Z.COGIPF_LOGON_OPERATION <>'Logon' where T.COGIPFSTATUS='Success' And Z.COGIPFSTATUS ='Success' And T.COGIPF_LOGON_OPERATION='Logon'

Comment: When there is a record which dint recieve a logoff or logon expired is not shown in the table after the self join established.Can you help me out in understanding where am I making mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If a session only can have a single logon and logoff event (that is, if each logon starts a new session) then you could skip the join altogether and use conditional selection and the max() function to flatten the result:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN LoginOperation = 'Logon' THEN RequestID END) RequestID, 
    SessionID, UserID, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN LoginOperation = 'Logon' THEN LoginOperation END) LoginOperation1, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN LoginOperation = 'Logon' THEN Time END) Time1, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN LoginOperation <> 'Logon' THEN LoginOperation END) LoginOperation2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LoginOperation <> 'Logon' THEN Time END) Time2 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY SessionID, UserID
```

And if we can assume that logon always happens before logoff and that there will always be a pair then you could reduce it further to:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(RequestID) RequestID, 
    SessionID, UserID, 'Logon' as LoginOperation1, 
    MIN(Time) Time1, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN LoginOperation <> 'Logon' THEN LoginOperation END) LoginOperation2,
    MAX(Time) Time2 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY SessionID, UserID
```

Comment: Assuming Logon always comes before Logoff and that the time fields are stored in a sane way, you can simplify this further and just use a simple MIN() for the RequestID and Time1 fields, hard-code 'Logon' for LoginOperation1, and use a simple MAX() for the Time2. Tempted to edit that into your answer.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Indeed, I didn't really think that far. And now my edit messed it up...